# Is 'anthreadic' an original word?

Tags: etymology

I thought up 'anthreadic' to describe a person who doesn't know which way to turn a tap or turn a nut on a bolt. It rolls off the tongue better than 'dysthreadic'. Has 'anthreadic' been used before?

Comment: A quick google nGrams search turns up nada for *anthreadic* or *dysthreadic*. I can check other corpora for you, like COCA or GLoWBE, but I don't have much hope. I'm sure one word or the other has been used online in various forums, but nowhere near enough to establish usage. I'd say, as it stands today, both are nonce forms.

Comment: Maybe they’re just screwed up.

Comment: Yes, but anthreadics might think they're screwed down. It's hard to know.

Comment: Hence the expression, 'I didn't know which way to turn'?

Comment: Note that there probably is a term in medicine, physiology, or psychology which refers to someone who cannot distinguish there right hand from their left.

Comment: I think an argument can be made for both. Dystreadic should describe the person who wants to turn the tap the wrong way. Anthreadic should describe the tap that doesn't turn the way I want it to.

Comment: In creating a distinction between anthreadic and dysthreadic, and nailing the sense in which dysthreadic should be used, you have at a stroke, doubled the world's understanding of this momentarily-crippling and time-sapping affliction. And now for the cure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [google](https://www.google.com/), there is no record of **anthreadic** having been used on the web.

According to a search on Google ngrams, there's no record of it having been printed in a book.

I would say the answer is **yes**, it is an original word.